# Why is edit_count exposed on Comments but not Questions or Answers

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

Comments have an `edit_count` field, why is this field not included with Question and Answer responses?

Further, the `edit_count` field has limited utility on a comment where, lacking revisions and a very short editable window, really would be better represented by a boolean value.

On the other hand, an integer `edit_count` field on a question or answer (revision count) would provide an interesting metric on the post without the need to query for revisions, which as anyone who has done so knows, is an excruciatingly slow process and I am sure that the servers don't like it much either.

It seems that comments, questions and answers are all 'post' objects and as such are likely derived from the same table which contains an `edit_count` field.

I suggest that `edit_count` should be included on all posts.

Comment: Ya, probably this would have been nice. How would it be useful though? You mention `"...would provide an interesting metric..."` but can you elaborate further?

Comment: @geo- one example: if edit_count == 0, post has not been edited - obviates the need to make a request to /revisions

Comment: Very good example. +1 for the question.

Comment: +1 for this `feature-request` (inherently useful as outlined, and API symmetry is a good thing anyway where applicable) - why don't just make it one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field will be revisited in a subsequent API version.  It is... less than ideal in v1.